# Can I draw free hand figures in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to add free hand drawings to my map. I tried the "Rectangles Ovals Digitizing" plugin but am looking for a free hand (not rectangle or circle) tool.
Also is there a plugin similar to the revision cloud in Autocad?

Comment: It's not really 'free hand' but the closest tool I have seen is from the 'Digitizing' tools (right-click on toolbar to see if it's enabled). You edit a layer, then add a node using atleast 3 left mouse-clicks then finish off by a right-click. Or have you already tried this?

Comment: you can use the [spline](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spline/) plugin.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the "Freehand Editing" plugin. Do a search for it in the plugins menu.